# Implementing Gridfs with Mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gridfs, mongomapper

I need to implement large documents in Mongomapper so I'm planning to use Gridfs, do you know any gem implementation for this? Joint and Grip are are also not working, so please let me know if there is any alternative.

Comment: Both the mongodb ruby driver and Mongoid natively support this.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I'm using Mongomapper right now but I'll try with Mongoid as it supports Gridfs. Thanks a lot.